# Can't mock useCallback jest unit test cases

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to write unit test cases using Jest. I have one  component to show the pop-up message. After the pop-up dialogue box appears there are two buttons 'Yes' and 'No'. when press on 'yes' button calling function with **"const confirmCancelPendingRequest = React.useCallback(() => {}"**. So could you please help me with how can I mock React.useCallback function. Thanks in advance.

```
 const confirmCancelPendingRequest = React.useCallback(() => {
  console.log('confirmCancelPendingRequest CALLED');
  setPendingRequest(true);
  cancelPendingRequest();
  closeCancelPendingRequest();
}, [closeCancelPendingRequest, cancelPendingRequest]);

screen = render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Confirm isOpen={true} onYes={onYes} onNo={onNo} text={text}/>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </Provider>,
);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach. You are testing a subtle implementation detail. What if in the next version you omit the `useCallback` (which most likely is just an optimisation). Instead test the result: state changes, external calls (mock them).